# using printrand within a url?

Tags: php

is there any way to use printrand() or something similar to generate random numbers from inside of a url call in a php script or html page? Basically, have a url, but on each load, I need the page to call url(dot)com/blah####blah with the #s being random each time.... How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can we see the pertinent part of your code that this needs to go into?

Comment: Why is this tagged both  PHP and Perl?

Answer (score 1):

When a page is requested by a URI (URL), the URI cannot be changed by a server-side language by any means other than redirection. You could, then redirect a request to `http://mydomain.com` to `http://mydomain.com/RANDOM` with code such as this:

```
$random = mt_rand();
header('location:http://mydomain.com/'.$random);
```

Be aware, however, that any random-number generating scheme is not going to be truly, 100% random, nor are you guaranteed that the random values will be unique for the same user or for different users. There is a possibility (and not a small one) that a random number will be duplicated.

Other than utilizing redirection, there is no way to change, server-side, the request URL after the request has been sent. That said, you can also push browser history states with javascript after the page has loaded. See the ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)), but be aware that this is new functionality; it has not been implemented on all user-agents, will NOT be implemented in older user-agents (Internet Explorer < 8), and is still in draft status (mechanics and API may change).

Answer (score -1):

You can append strings in PHP with a period. And you can use PHP's rand(min, max) function. Something like this:

```
$url = "http://www.url.com/" . rand(1, 10);
```

Further, you probably only want whole numbers, so use ceil() or round():

```
$url = "http://www.url.com/" . ceil(rand(1, 10));
```

Comment: `rand(1, 10)` will always return an integer so `ceil` is unnecessary. Furthermore, you should abandon `rand` and use `mt_rand` instead.

Comment: is there any way to add it within the url such as: url(dot)com/blah####blahblah

Comment: Agreed, the use of `ceil` on numbers that can only be whole is not necessary, and the use of the less-powerful `rand` is always discouraged. Further, this answer does not appear to address the question. While it certainly isn't a very clearly worded question, I do not think it a reasonable interpretation that the question was regarding methods to concatenate strings. -1